# How to detect cell for adding badge on it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, logic, badge

I have a function, which adds badge on cell:

```
unreadMessagesCountBadge(cell, forCount: messagesCount)
```

but I do not know, how to detect cell what I need for adding this badge on it?

For example, I have a users list and one of my contacts sent me a message. How to detect this cell, to add near this contact my badge `1`?

**UPDATE**

I detect that new message received in another file and I need to call this function from there and update in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I'm confused =/

Comment: create a badge property in user list. add your badge to it and refresh the table view. also handle the badge property in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: and one more question, you just touched this topic. How to **update** my tableView? When I do `reloadData( )` it doesn't help me. So, I need to change my controller and return back to see my badge. Any ideas about this problem? @x4h1d

Comment: `reloadData( )` should work fine if you handle updated data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` correctly. Changing `viewcontroller`, just to refresh table view, will be ridiculous. Check `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method if your reload doesn't work. put break point and debug.

Comment: @x4h1d I've updated my question. Please read

Comment: I thing you should have used `singleton` class to handle data, as you said in your update that data is manipulated in different view controller and/or class. Create a singleton model class. Singleton [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383452/objective-c-sample-singleton-implementation). Or you can invoke method in another class, which aren't connected to each other, via `NSNotificationCenter`.

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't it help you when using `reloadData()` on your tableView?
Are you calling it from the main thread? You can force calling from main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
  self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```